# Neo4j cypher return all nodes where property and relationship matches any array element

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've used an image classifier AI to create a Neo4j database. There are 30 `Category` nodes with an `id` property. The `CLASSIFIED_AS` relationships have a `weight` property between 0 and 1.

I have two arrays for category `id` and relationship `weight`: `[14, 17, 20, 21]`, `[0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4]`.

I know how to return images that fall into one of the categories in my array.

```
MATCH (i:Image)-[:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category)
WHERE c.id IN [14, 17, 20, 21]
RETURN i LIMIT 100
```

But how do I filter images by both category and corresponding relationship weight?

So in this example, I require:

1. Images that are in category 14 with a CLASSIFIED_AS weight between 0.9 to 1
2. And that are in category 17 with a CLASSIFIED_AS weight between 0.7 to 1
3. And that are in category 20 with a CLASSIFIED_AS weight between 0.5 to 1
4. And that are in category 21 with a CLASSIFIED_AS weight between 0.4 to 1

How is this possible with arrays of varying lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE]

This update should satisfy the example at the bottom of your question.

For simplicity, I will assume that `Category` `id` values are strings. I will also assume you pass this `$input` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) value:

```
{
  14: {lo: 0.9, hi: 1},
  17: {lo: 0.7, hi: 1},
  20: {lo: 0.5, hi: 1},
  21: {lo: 0.4, hi: 1}
}
```

This query will find the `Image`s that satisfy all the constraints in `$input`:

```
MATCH (i:Image)-[r:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category)
WHERE $input[c.id].lo <= r.weight <= $input[c.id].hi
WITH i, COUNT(DISTINCT c) AS catCount
WHERE catCount = SIZE(KEYS($input))
RETURN i LIMIT 100
```

[ORIGINAL]

Assuming you pass the lists as the [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `$ids` and `$weights`, this should work:

```
MATCH (i:Image)-[r:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category)
WHERE c.id IN $ids AND r.weight IN $weights
RETURN DISTINCT i LIMIT 100
```

But if you actually want to specify a weight *range*, then pass a `$range` parameter in this format: `{lo: 0.9, hi: 1}`, and use this query:

```
MATCH (i:Image)-[r:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category)
WHERE c.id IN $ids AND $range.lo <= r.weight <= $range.hi
RETURN DISTINCT i LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on parameters. But I think your query is not strict enough. In my original example, I want it to return images classified as all 4 categories, each with their own specific weight range. I think your query returns images with at least one category.

Comment: I don't want c.id = 14 OR c.id = 17 OR c.id = 20 OR c.id = 21
I want c.id = 14 AND c.id = 17 AND c.id = 20 AND c.id = 21

Comment: I have updated to my answer to solve the example at the bottom of your question.

Comment: I love the simplicity of your updated answer but I'm getting an error passing the input parameter to it. Expected Long(8) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue

Comment: As indicated, I assumed you stored your Category id's as strings. Just change them to strings, and the Cypher code will not have to change.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, which is fully reproducible.

Create the nodes and relationships. Only the imageids ending in 1 will be returned.

```
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 11})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.95}]->(:Category {id: 14})
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 10})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.89}]->(:Category {id: 14})
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 21})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.73}]->(:Category {id: 17})
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 20})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.65}]->(:Category {id: 17})
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 31})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.55}]->(:Category {id: 20})
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 30})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.47}]->(:Category {id: 20})
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 41})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.42}]->(:Category {id: 21})
CREATE (:Image {imageid: 40})-[:CLASSIFIED_AS {weight: 0.37}]->(:Category {id: 21})
```

Now for a combination of collect(), unwind, nested list creation, and list comprehension:

```
WITH [0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4] as weights
MATCH (i:Image)-[r:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category)
WHERE c.id in [14, 17, 20, 21]
WITH weights, i.imageid as iid, r.weight as rw, c.id as cid
ORDER BY c.id
WITH weights, cid, collect(iid) as myims, collect(rw) as rweights
with weights, [myims, rweights] as myrwims
with weights, collect(myrwims) as allrwims
WITH weights, [i in range(0, size(allrwims)-1) | [allrwims[i], weights[i]]] as allrwimswithweights
unwind allrwimswithweights as x
with x, weights, x[0] as x40, x[0][1] as x401, x[1] as x41
with *, [i in range(0, size(x[0][1])-1) WHERE x[0][1][i] >= x[1] | x[0][0][i]] as finalims
return x, x40, x401, x41, finalims
```

Notes:

- The whole goal of this is to get it into a form like `[[[imageids], [weights]], [comparison weight]]`
- I left the versions of x in the return so it's clear what is happening with all the indexes
- If you want the Image nodes instead of the imageids, just change `i.imageid as iid` to `i as iid`

Comment: Your data creation code seems flawed. It can creates duplicate `Category` and `Image` nodes.

Comment: Yes it could! My graph contained no Image or Category nodes, so running it once was fine.

Comment: Your CREATE code is creating 2 instances of each `Category`. Presumably, `:Category(id)` should be unique. This happens the first time you run the code.

Comment: For this solution, I didn't consider it necessary that every Category node have a unique id; I was trying to keep the creation code short.